# Python - Joining 8 bit words to form 24 bit word

Tags: python

I am trying to create a clock from a 24 bit counter. The Counter generates its count in 3 8 bit words that need to be joined together to form a 24 bit word. I would convert the 24 bit word to a floating number and multiply that by the standard time for each increment of the counter. I have code of the following:

```
SensTime1 = myBoard.Read(0x18)   #Low Byte
SensTime2 = myBoard.Read(0x19)
SensTime3 = myBoard.Read(0x1A)   #High Byte
SensTimeB = (SensTime3 |SensTime2 | SensTime1)
SensTimeC = float(SensTimeB) * .00003425
```

The problem is that SensTimeB statement doesn't seem to be joining the byte values of SensTime1, 2 and 3 together properly to form a 24 bit word

Comment: You are combining the three bytes as a single byte: SensTimeB needs to be created by combining the shifted values of the middle byte (8 bits left) and high byte (16 bits left)

Comment: Try some simple debugging: print the three bytes and the value of `SensTimeB`.

Comment: The `|` operator does not do what you think it does.

Comment: How do I create the 24 bit word that I can then convert to a decimal value? I suppose I could multiply the "high" word by "65536", the middle word by "256" and the low word by "1" and add them together but I was thinking there might be a more elegant "convert the 24 bit word to decimal" solution.

Comment: Even if there were a more “elegant” method, try your multiply method, or use bit shifting, and get the basic functionality working first, then you can decide if it’s worth worrying about “elegance”